# Old version of scientific python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python program, written around 2001. I cant get it to run because a lot of the function s aren't recognised.

My best guess is that this is because the program was written using the scientific python modules based on the now deprecated numerical python, rather than its successor, numpy. I have been able to download the old numerical python, but I can't find old scientific python modules, only later ones based on numpy.

Does anyone know where I can download the old scientific python modules based on the deprecated numerical python?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to an old version from 2003.](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/python/OldFiles/src/SciPy-0.2.0_alpha_200.4161/)

You might also have to get a different python interpreter as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, good find, but unfortunately the program doesn't run.

Comment: Is it possibly the numerical package here: https://sourcesup.renater.fr/frs/?group_id=180